# How to remove space at the bottom of imgs CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and have created two images stacked on top of each other in an html/css document, however, there is a space between them that I cannot get rid of (example in image below). I have included my code and was wondering if anyone had an easy solution to this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r4AG.jpg)

```css
:root {
  --color-offblack: #252422;
  --color-brown: #403D39;
  --color-lightbrown: #CCC5B9;
  --color-offwhite: #FFFCF2;
  --color-orange: #EB5E28;
  --width: 84%;
  --mobile-width: 92%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-offblack);
  background: var(--color-offwhite);
}

.container {
  width: var(--width);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}

a {
  color: var(--color-offblack);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  color: var(--color-offblack);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.4rem;
  line-height: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h4,
h5 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: var(--color-offblack);
  color: var(--color-offwhite);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: var(--color-offwhite);
  color: var(--color-offblack);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-offblack);
}

.btn-primary {
  background: var(--color-orange);
  color: var(--color-offwhite);
}

section {
  max-width: 100vw;
  padding: 12rem 0 0;
}


/* NAVBAR */

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 7rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--color-offwhite);
}

nav button {
  display: none;
}

nav .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .container ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
}

nav .container ul a {
  padding: 0 0 0.3rem;
}

nav .container ul a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-orange);
}

nav .container ul a.highlight {
  color: var(--color-orange);
}

nav a:hover {
  color: var(--color-orange);
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--color-offwhite);
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex !important;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 180px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 22px 14px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--color-orange);
}


/* END OF NAVBAR */


/* HEADER */

header {
  background: var(--color-lightbrown);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 5rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center top;
}

header.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30rem auto 17rem;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}

.content-wrapper h2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -350px;
  color: var(--color-offwhite);
  text-align: center left;
}

.content-wrapper a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -260px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Samuel Horton Jr</title>

  <!--- GOOGLE FONTS-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <!--- ICONSCOUT CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

  <!--- STYLESHEEET-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <a hrefs="index.html" class="logo"><img src="./images/logo.png"></a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="myWork.html">my work</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="greaseSolutions.html">grease solutions LLC</a></li>
            <li><a href="minirig.html">minirig</a></li>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="myself.html">myself</a></li>
        <li><a href="otherCreations.html">other creations</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="highlight">hire me</a></li>
      </ul>


      <button id="menu-button"><i class="uil uil-bars"></i></i></i></button>
      <button id="close-button"><i class="uil uil-multiply"></i></i></i></button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--END OF NAVBAR-->

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <img src="images/greaseSolutionsBackground.png">
        <h2>Grease Solutions LLC</h2>
        <div class="cta">
          <a href="greaseSolutions.html" class="btn btn-primary">clean up</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <img src="images/minirigBackground.png">
        <h2>Minirig</h2>
        <div class="cta">
          <a href="minirig.html" class="btn btn-primary">turn up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for any post/formatting mistakes, I am new to all of this so please bear with me!

Comment: What you do is edit the IMAGE to remove the whitespace.  Don't try to solve this problem with CSS.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is not the solution. There is no extra white space on the image, the space is filled in with the background color declared by CSS which means it is surely a problem with my code.

Comment: You have `height: 500px` set on the images. Are they less than 500px high?

Comment: Sam, the best solution would be to fix the aspect ratio of the images before using them. You can use object-fit: cover, but this is not the best solution

Comment: @Sam can't tell if this will actually fix the problem without you adding a stack snippet to your question that reproduces the problem, but note that images by default are `display: inline`, which means they are affected by `line-height`. In all likelihood, you can fix the problem by setting the images' `line-height` to `1`, or you can set them to be `display: block`, in which case line height won't affect them.

Comment: just tested this locally, add height 500px to `.content-wrapper` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam. I 've read your question carefully.
Your  is 500px in height but your .content-wrapper is not 500px, so I inserted height:500px in your css file.

```
.content-wrapper {
   height:500px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your content-wrapper class

```
.content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/suhitomiyu/edit?html,css,js,output)